# .NET Web API returns double with a lot of decimal places

Tags: c#, .net, json, double, rounding

I am using .Net Web API to return information that has doubles. Before I return I round those doubles to two decimal places. When I print them I get(f.e): 145,92. All great. But when I return that double, my JSON response is created with a double like this:

> "hours":145.92000000000002

Any ideas what is creating this issue?

My rounding function is:

```
public double ApplyRounding(double value, int digits)
    {
        decimal decValue = (decimal)value;
        // First round is to fix rounding errors by changing things like 0.99499999999999 to 0.995
        decValue = Math.Round(decValue, digits + 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        decValue = Math.Round(decValue, digits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        return (double)decValue;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is how C# interprets `double`. `double` does not have the same floating point precision as `float`, regarding the decimals. Use `float` for a more precise representation of your decimal numbers.

Comment: @AlexBarac did you mean `decimal` instead of `float`?

Comment: @oleksii No... I used to work on a pseudo-random generator program, which performed poorly with `double` and excellent with `float`, because of the rounding problems that `double` operations create, which seem to be the problem that OP is having as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's known as "double rounding" problems. You get it from converting your double to decimal, performing math on it, then converting back to double.

A few related links:

Here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/

Here: [Decimal rounding errors upon division (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910588/decimal-rounding-errors-upon-division-c)

Here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I managed to solve this with you answer and the comments above by using decimal instead of double->decimal->double. My JSON is now created with the correct number of decimal places